# merge and sort two range of numbers

Tags: python, merge

In this code, which is a calculation of meridian distance in Lambert cartographic projection, I need to merge the range calculations of x and x2 in one simplified calculation.

Results of x are >= 0 
Results of x2 are <= 0

How to merge range calculations of x and x2 in one? Preferred result would be starting with lowest negative number and ending with highest possitive number that will come out as an output.

I'm not sure if it's possible to use sorted() on the outputs here. I could also make a list from the results and then simply call list.sort(), but with my code knowledge I'm not sure how to write it correctly.

Here is the code:

```
if projection == "L":
    print("Lambert projection")
    s = int(input("Define scale 1:(input)"))
    if s <= 0:
        sys.exit("scale must have higher value than 0")
    v = int(input("Define longitude interval of meridians"))
    if v <= 0:
        sys.exit("Interval must have higher value than 0")
    n = int(input("How many meridians to project? (from center)"))
    if n <=0:
        sys.exit("Number must be higher than 0")
    for v in range(n):
        x = R*(v*n)
        if x/s<100:
            print("meridian will be", x/s, "cm from center")
        else:
            print("meridian will be - cm from center")
    for v in range(n):
        x2 = R*(-v*n)
        print("meridian will be", x2/s, "cm from center")
```

The result i get from range now:

```
meridian will be 0.0 cm from center
meridian will be 1.1467998 cm from center
meridian will be 2.2935996 cm from center
meridian will be 3.4403994 cm from center

meridian will be 0.0 cm from center
meridian will be -1.1467998 cm from center
meridian will be -2.2935996 cm from center
meridian will be -3.4403994 cm from center
```

The expected result:

```
meridian will be -3.4403994 cm from center
meridian will be -2.2935996 cm from center
meridian will be -1.1467998 cm from center
meridian will be 0.0 cm from center
meridian will be 1.1467998 cm from center
meridian will be 2.2935996 cm from center
meridian will be 3.4403994 cm from center
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try doing it with a list comprehension.

```
 x = list(map(lambda v: R * (v * n) / s, range(n)))
 x.extend(map(lambda v: R * (-v * n) / s, range(n)))
 x = list(filter(lambda v: v < 100, x))
 x_sorted = sorted(x)
```

What I did here was used the `extend` method, which works similarly to using the `__add__` operator except that extend doesn't create a new list but adds values to the current lists, which means it's somewhat faster. Also, list comprehensions tend to be faster than for loops in Python and they're easier to read to boot.

So, if you run with `R = 6371.11`, `s = 100000` and `n = 18`, you should get:

```
[-19.4955966, -18.3487968, -17.201997, -16.0551972, -14.9083974, -13.7615976, -12.6147978, 
 -11.467998, -10.3211982, -9.1743984, -8.0275986, -6.8807988, -5.733999, -4.5871992, 
 -3.4403994, -2.2935996, -1.1467998, 0.0, 0.0, 1.1467998, 2.2935996, 3.4403994, 4.5871992, 
 5.733999, 6.8807988, 8.0275986, 9.1743984, 10.3211982, 11.467998, 12.6147978, 13.7615976, 
 14.9083974, 16.0551972, 17.201997, 18.3487968, 19.4955966]
```

Comment: This code really seems like faster solution, but when I tried it, the program crashed with 
error:
    `x = [R * (v * n) for v in range(n) if (x / s) < 100]
    NameError: name 'x' is not defined. `
            Not sure if it's Python version issue, but it doesn't seem to recognize the x variable when it's defined as list.

Comment: @MartinDare You are correct; that was an oversight on my part. Instead, I used the `filter` method to remove anything where `x / s > 100`. It'll achieve the same result

Comment: This code works, but only with negative numbers, with x > 0 it multiplies the result too many times if i input v=10 and n=18.
I printed the list using this code: `for i in x_sorted:
            print("meridan will be {}".format(i))`

here is the result I get:`meridan will be 0.0
meridan will be 114679.98
meridan will be 229359.96
meridan will be 344039.94
meridian will be 0.0 cm from center
meridian will be -0.12742219999999999 cm from center
`

Comment: @MartinDare Isn't that dependent on the values for R and s? I'm not sure what values you used and I'm not sure which results you expected. The core of this code is still the `R * (v * n)` that you had in your original question.

Comment: @MartinDare After some further investigation, I've updated my answer. I hope this helps

Comment: Yes it helped, the values are: `R=6371.11, v=10, n=18, s=100000` but i still get one set of extra results that I don't know where are they coming from. 
I get the sorted results, `meridan will be -2.2935996
meridan will be -1.1467998
meridan will be 0.0
meridan will be 0.0
meridan will be 1.1467998
meridan will be 2.2935996`
 but then I get an extra set of values:
`meridian will be 0.0 cm from center
meridian will be -0.12742219999999999 cm from center
meridian will be -0.25484439999999997 cm from center`

Comment: @MartinDare I added the output after running just the my response code along with the inputs you provided. I hope that helps for debugging purposes

Answer (score 1):

You can just add them normally and apply `sorted` on it after converting them in a list, as you guessed. `sorted` by default sort in ascending order,

```
# initialize lists at the top of your code,

l1 = [] 
l2 = []
```

you can then append to both lists on each iteration,

replace,

```
x = R*(v*n)
        if x/s<100:
            print("meridian will be", x/s, "cm from center")
```

with,

```
x = R*(v*n)
        if x/s<100:
            l1.append(x/s)
```

Do the same for `x2`

at the end create a sorted list,

```
sorted_list = sorted(l1 + l2)
```

print sorted list,

```
for i in sorted_list:
        print("meridan will be {}".format(i))
```

Comment: Well it seems to append all range inputs at once giving me a large number, where should I put x.append? After the range or before it?

Comment: does x has one value or range of values?

Comment: Can you tell me what are values of `x` and `x2` @MartinDare

Comment: R = 6371,11, v = 10, n =18, s = 100000
x values are 0.0, 1.14, 2.29, 3.44...
edit: x2 values are 0.0, - 1.14, -2.29, -3.44...
so it has range of values

Comment: you can replace `x = R*(v*n)` with `x.append(R*(v*n))`. Similarly for `x2`, and in the end after the loops, you can print list of values in sorted order `print(sorted(x + x2))`

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try it. I don't have time for it now though, thanks for help.

Comment: @MartinDare, i have updated the answer please have a look